# JSTL formatDate ignoring locale

Tags: java, localization, jstl

I want to localize dates with JSTL, and I am trying to do it like below.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:setLocale value="da_DK" scope="application" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${some.date}" dateStyle="FULL" />
```

`some.date` is a `java.util.Date` instance. I have played around with various different locales, but nothing is working. I get the following output no matter which locale I choose: *Tuesday, January 13, 2015*. I also tried the following, after removing the above call to `setLocale()`:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />

<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="FULL" />

<fmt:setLocale value="fr_FR" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="FULL" />
```

The above outputs *Tuesday, January 13, 2015* two times, and the same happens for every locale that I tried. The only thing I have configured related to locale is the following (Spring MVC project):

```
@Bean
public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    Locale locale = new Locale("dk");

    CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(locale);

    return localeResolver;
}
```

Shouldn't the text be translated into the language defined by the locale, or the format changed at the very least? Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? I tried every example that I could find online, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just change the scope to `session` as below

```
<fmt:setLocale value="fr_FR" scope="session"/>

Date in France:
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="full"/> <br/>

<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session"/>
 Date in US: 
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" dateStyle="full" /> <br/>
```

Comment: For some reason, it only works with the scope set to `session`. I was pretty sure I had tried that already, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: Any other ideas? I have the same problem, but my site doesn't use sessions (it is stateless). Therefore scope="session" doesn't work - it actually gives the error that the page does not participate in a session. scope="request" has no effect.