# Why does JSTL's fmt:setLocale tag only work with scope set to session?

Tags: jsp, localization, jstl

My web application has a default locale, which is based on the country that the server is in. However, jobs created on the system could be based in another country so could quite easily have a different locale. On a certain page, I am temporarily (within page scope) trying to set the locale using JSTL's `fmt:setLocale` tag to the locale of the job on display, but it isn't working.

I'm using it like so, where *currentLocale* is the locale code of the job (e.g. en_GB or en_HK).

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${currentLocale}"/>
```

I've even specifically set it to one of the above locale codes:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_HK"/>
```

But then when it comes to using the `fmt:formatNumber` function, the currency isn't set properly:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${dailyRate}" type="currency"/>
```

This uses the default locale of en_US so the currency symbol is the dollar, not *HKD* as it should be in the above example!

However, when I change the scope of the locale to "session" it works and uses the correct currency code:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_HK" scope="session"/>
```

But I don't want to be overriding the session's locale for obvious reasons. Does anybody know why this is the case or if there is a workaround for this issue? I have seen comments on other questions on Stack Overflow where the odd person has said the `setLocale` tag only works when scope is set to session, but no one has explained why this might be the case.

Just for reference, here is a related question I found where people have had a similar issue: [JSTL formatDate ignoring locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925049/jstl-formatdate-ignoring-locale)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How's the application going to know what language to serve if a session variable for it isn't set?

Comment: It is already set elsewhere. I am needing to temporarily change it for certain pages, so I can format currencies depending on the location of the job being displayed.

Comment: "It is already set elsewhere." If you set it as a request parameter, as soon as you go to a different page - the variable will be null.... If you're not using sessions how are you storing what language is currently set?

Comment: The locale of the web application _is_ set in the session. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that. I need to temporarily tell JSTL to override that on a couple of pages so I can format the currencies, etc.